# Is there anyway to show a card/container/div on top of hovered stepper in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular13, angular-material-stepper

I want to create a tools card to manage steps and show it on top when the mouse is hovered on step like the picture below :
[image]

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Prime Ng has an implementation for that ([steps](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/steps/personal)).
You can override some styles and achieve the same functionality as you describe

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is "Kendo UI for Angular"
Please refer below URL

[Kendo UI for Angular Tooltip]https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/tooltips/tooltip/